# "zsh: unknown file attribute: 0" passing a Python tuple on the command line

Tags: python, zsh

I am calling a Python (3.8) script from Terminal on Mac using zsh (5.8) leading to the error message in the title. I found a workaround for this problem (albeit not elegant), but I would like to *understand* what is going wrong.

My Python file `test.py`:

```py
import argparse
from ast import literal_eval

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
parser.add_argument("--test", default="", type=str, help="test")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(literal_eval(args.test))
```

Calling this script from command line using `python test.py --test (0.4,0.3)` results in this error message `zsh: unknown file attribute: 0`

**What does that mean?**

---

Explanation about `literal_eval`:

`literal_eval` takes a string like `"(0.3,0.4)"` and evaluates it as tuple s.t.

```py
a = literal_eval("(0.3,0.4)")
type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: You don't need Python to reproduce this problem. `echo --test (0.4,0.3)` would do the same thing.

Comment: Your user interface should not expect the user to understand Python syntax. If you need a tuple, do something like `add_argument('--test', nargs=2, type=float)` instead.

Comment: For what zsh does with a paren at the end of a (even empty) string undergoing filename generation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Comment: @chepner thanks for the tip. didn't know nargs. with nargs=* it is perfect for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best workaround would be to put the string in quotes, so you would call it like:

```bash
python test.py --test '(0.4,0.3)'
```

The reason of the error is that `zsh` tries to use globbing magic to expand `(0.4,0.3)` into filenames, but of course since you don't intend to use it you don't have the syntax quite right, thus the error. Just use quotes `'` or `"` for strings, and `zsh` won't try to parse the argument, it will just pass the argument straight to the `python` command

Comment: You save my day!